# How to convert Gtk.Image to base64

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk, imgur

I have a Gtk.Image object and I want to convert it's data to a base64 encoded string (for use with [imgur](http://api.imgur.com/examples)). How would I achieve that?

Comment: I am guessing you want a base64 encoded string of a file image format (png, jpeg, gif, etc...) and not a the actual Gtk.Image object, right?

Comment: Yeah, I think imgur expects a base64 encoded png, jpeg et cetera

Comment: So, what is the source of the data that gets loaded into the Gtk.Image?  Does it get loaded from such a file?

Comment: I don't exactly know where it comes from. I get it from the api of a clipboard manager (Diodon).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Has to run it through a gdk.pixbuf, but this seems the easiest:

```
import cStringIO
import base64

pixBuf = gtkImage.get_pixbuf()

fH = cStringIO.StringIO() 
pixBuf.save_to_callback(fH.write, "png") 
encodedBuffer = base64.b64encode(fH.getvalue()) #base64 encoded png
```

Comment: I believe this is the right answer. But unfortunately these methods seem [broken on Ubuntu](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/888305)...

Comment: A possible workaround is to get the image data with `pixbuf.get_pixels` (returns str) or `pixbuf.get_pixels_array` (returns numpy array), and then go through Cairo or PIL; not sure how, though.